# Build error while building android source code on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android

I was building android source code on my ubuntu 12.04, which I update to latest version of ubuntu and android (repo sync).
After that I tried to build android source code(clean build).I got the following build error

```
> host SharedLib: libOpenglRender
> (out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libOpenglRender.so) host Prebuilt:
> eventanalyzer
> (out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/eventanalyzer_intermediates/eventanalyzer)
> Install: out/host/linux-x86/bin/exc_dump Install:
> out/host/linux-x86/bin/fastboot Install:
> out/host/linux-x86/bin/fs_config Install:
> out/host/linux-x86/bin/fs_get_stats Install:
> out/host/linux-x86/bin/genext2fs Install:
> out/host/linux-x86/bin/gpttool host Prebuilt: hierarchyviewer
> (out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/hierarchyviewer_intermediates/hierarchyviewer)
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
> make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libOpenglRender.so] Error 1
> make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I did find the solution on the internet..

Answer (score 2):

If you installed Ubuntu 12.04 64bit to compile Android 2.3.5 (gingerbread), 
run the below command:

```
apt-get install lib32z1-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Google uses as a test system Ubuntu 10.04 and has produced the instructions how to build a system for this system. If you're using other system it's left for your own responsibility. Thus, I recommend you to use Ubuntu 10.04. Moreover, 12.04 is still a beta version and there can be problems that influence on the build process.